# Connecting to Vagrant Box with MySQL Workbench

Tags: ssh, vagrant, mysql-workbench, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I'm getting started with Vagrant.

I'm trying to connect to [Scotch Box](https://box.scotch.io/) with MySQL Workbench.

First I did succeed to connect to mysql with a PHP script inside the box, but I can't do it with MySQL Workbench.

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

I've got the error message: "Could not connect the SSH Tunnel"
[image: MySQL Workbench error message]

I've edited the file "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to bind-address = 0.0.0.0

I'm on Windows 10

Thank you very much for helping me, I don't know what's wrong, everything I already read online and tried didn't worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found where was my issue. I wasn't using the right **SSH key file**...

To find the the location of your key file:

-> Execute **vagrant ssh-config** in your Vagrant directory.

So my config for this scotch-box:

*SSH Hostname: **192.168.33.10***

*SSH Username: **vagrant***

*SSH Password: **vagrant***

*SSH Key File: **your-path-here***

*MySQL Hostname: **127.0.0.1***

*MySQL Server Port: **3306***

*Username: **root***

*Password: **root***

Answer (score 0):

For developers using puphpet

Choose Standard TCP/IP over SSH

Parameters (Mostly default values since I did not change it)

```
SSH Hostname: 192.168.56.101
SSH Username: vagrant
SSH Password: vagrant
SSH Key File: C:\cygwin64\home\(username)\puphpet\sutfva\puphpet\files\dot\ssh\id_rsa
MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1
MySQl Server Port: 3306
Username: root
Password: 123
```